# How to change colour of outline in Krita

Tags: color, krita, outline

How would I change the colour of an outline? For example, this:

[image]

I would like to change the colour of the outline (which, the colour is currently brown) to black. Would this be possible in Krita?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When colouring line art, it's a good idea to make sure to keep your line art on a separate layer from the colour fills. That way you should be able to use a filter on the line art layer to change its colour without affecting the other layers.

An example. Here the original line art is black. Using the HSV/HSL Adjustment with the colourize option checked, I changed the line art to blue.

[image]

If your line art is brown and you want to make it black, you could remove the colour using the Desaturate filter, then use the Levels filter to make it darker

Comment: I tried setting the Hue to 268, but the farthest I can get is 180: https://ibb.co/1K8Nvkw

Comment: @Crownie - looks like you have a different version of Krita from me. The numbers likely don't matter, only the position of the slider. You'll need to experiment.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll try this out. Thank you very much for all your help, @BillyKerr!